# browser session issue in jmeter

Tags: session, browser, jmeter

Iam testing an application which has the following behaviour
User1 loged into machine A using IE Then User2 cannot login into
Machine A using IE. So User2 should login from Machine B.
I have recorded the script using IE  and when trying to test with 10 user load say U1 to U10, only U1 is able to login and rest all are failing....how do i simulatd the load in this case.
I checked with developers and they are not using IP address for this but using browser session for making single user logs in from a single browser.
Could you please help how do i overcome the issue and simulate the load

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar), it can automatically handle cookies and define and maintain separate session for each thread.

If it doesn't help - inspect requests more closely with a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to compare which request bits are different for different users. The possible options are:

1. Cookies - can be handled by aforementioned HTTP Cookie Manager
2. Headers - can be handled by [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
3. Request parameters - it may be the case when server sends some parameter in the response and expects it to be present in the next request. In that case you need to extract it from the first response with i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), store it into a JMeter Variable and send with the next request.